# How to put Box in center of Flex when using Spacers

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui

So I have a header where I'm using `Flex`. In that header, there is an item I want to be aligned in the center of the header. Here is some example code demonstrating the

```js
return (
  <Box>
    <Box paddingTop={5} paddingBottom={5} paddingLeft={8} paddingRight={8}>
      <Flex alignItems="center" gap="2">
        <Box p={4} w="200px" bg="red" />
        <Box p={4} w="200px" bg="blue" />
        <Spacer />
        <Box p={4} w="200px" bg="purple" />
        <Spacer />
        <Box p={4} w="200px" bg="green" />
      </Flex>
    </Box>
  </Box>
);
```

As you can see, I have two boxes on the left, one in the middle, and one on the right, and I'm using Spacers to separate these 3 groups. What I want is for the purple box to align itself in the center of the outer box, but as you can see below, it does not.

[image: Purple box not in the middle]

Instead, it creates two Spacers of the same width, which results in the purple box being aligned right of center.

While still using Flex and Spacer, how can I make the purple box align in the center properly, where the middle of the box aligns with the center of the outer box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be wrap the `Box` in 3 sections taking the same width in the container with [`flex-grow: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow), and center content in the middle section. This would also omit the use of `Spacer`.

Example: (demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bh52tj?file=src/App.js))

```
<Box>
  <Box paddingTop={5} paddingBottom={5} paddingLeft={8} paddingRight={8}>
    <Flex justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" gap="2">
      <Flex alignItems="center" gap="2" flex="1" outline="3px solid hotpink">
        <Box p={4} maxW={"200px"} bg={"red"} flex="1 1" />
        <Box p={4} maxW={"200px"} bg={"blue"} flex="1 1" />
      </Flex>
      <Flex
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
        gap="2"
        flex="1"
        outline="3px solid hotpink"
      >
        <Box p={4} maxW={"200px"} bg={"purple"} flex="1 1" />
      </Flex>
      <Flex
        justifyContent="flex-end"
        alignItems="center"
        gap="2"
        flex="1"
        outline="3px solid hotpink"
      >
        <Box p={4} maxW={"200px"} bg={"green"} flex="1 1" />
      </Flex>
    </Flex>
  </Box>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can position the purple box in the center of the parent container with the following styles for the purple box:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

And add `position: relative` to the container

Comment: Absolute positioning is troublesome, especially when the elements overlap on smaller screens.